# Сумма n чисел в массиве

Tags: python

Вводится целое число `n` (это количество чисел `a`).

А во второй строке вводятся сами `a`: `a1`, `a2`, `a3`,.., `an`. Всё в одну строку.

Как реализовать такое на питоне?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример входных данных

Comment: Непонятно с чем именно проблема - как обработать ввод, как просуммировать, с чем-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если числа `a1..n` будут вводиться в одной строке, то по сути нам и не нужно `n`.

```
>>> print(sum(map(int, input().split())))
1 2 3 4
10
```

Comment: N осталась от методички по паскалю